# Can I upload a LIPIcs article to arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

Can I upload an article that appeared in a LIPIcs style conference proceedings to arXiv as is?

What changes are required other than removing the DOI data?

Comment: This should be explained in the conference policies / copyright agreement.

Comment: You should check the author agreement, but a safe option is to remove lipics branding, doi and so on. Your camera-ready version should fine, I think.

Comment: Helpful quote from the (2018) lipics manual (does NOT prove that your specific conference allows this): *The* `\hideLIPIcs` *command masks all information related to the series (e.g., copyright
information and a possible DOI specification) on the first page. This might be used
e.g. to prepare an extended version to be uploaded to arXiv.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the proceedings submission / permissions allow you to also submit your manuscript to arXiv, which presumably it will as there are other LIPIcs papers on arXiv, you can also provide the DOI and reference for the original publication in the arXiv record.

One such example is [Periodic Pólya urns and an application to Young tableaux](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03133), which has the following publication information attached.

> Journal reference: Leibniz International Proceedings in Informatics (LIPIcs), 29th International Conference on Probabilistic, Combinatorial and Asymptotic Methods for the Analysis of Algorithms (AofA 2018), pp.1-12
>
> DOI:   10.4230/LIPIcs.AofA.2018.11